Help Understanding Formula from ONAG
I've been reading through On Numbers and Games and I'm having trouble with the formula presented in the proof of Th. 22 for the formal sum $\sum_{y\in \textbf{No}}\omega^y\cdot r_y$
I tried to apply the formula to $\omega=\omega^1\cdot 1$ and I'm not sure where I went wrong
The formula presented in the proof is:
$
\sum_{y\in \textbf{No}}\omega^y\cdot r_y=\{\sum_{y>z}\omega^y\cdot r_y+\omega^z\cdot r_z^L|\sum_{y>z}\omega^y\cdot r_y+\omega^z\cdot r_z^R\}_{z\in \textbf{No}}
$
In the case of $\omega^1\cdot 1$, the only value of $z$ that would contribute to the options would be $z=1$, right? Because if $z$ is anything else, $r_z$ would be $0$, so $r_z^L$ and $r_z^R$ would be empty and contribute nothing to either option
If $z=1$, then $r_z=1$, so the right option of the set is empty (since $1^R$ is empty), and for the left option, the sum contributes nothing (since according to the paragraph prior to the theorem, "$r_y$ vanishes whenever y doesn't belong to a certain descending sequence", the sequence being $<1>$ in this case, and there's no element of that sequence greater than $z=1$. The $\omega^z\cdot r_z^L$ term becomes $\omega^1\cdot 1^L=\omega\cdot 0=0$, so the whole formula becomes $\{0|\}$, which is obviously not $\omega$. What am I misinterpreting here?
I suspect it's the $z\in \textbf{No}$ part. I'm not sure what this notation meant, and I was interpreting it to mean every $z\in \textbf{No}$ is contributing an option (the vast majority of which are empty, given $r_z=0$ unless $z=1$). Or maybe I'm misreading "$r_y$ must vanish whenever $y$ does not belong to a certain descending sequence", and this doesn't mean $r_y=0$ when $y$ isn't in the descending sequence of exponents. I don't know
On a related note, I'm really struggling with this book, and I think I'm missing a lot of prerequisites. I flew through chapters 1 and 2, but after that my comprehension significantly dropped off. I have copies of the first two volumes of Winning Ways, and An Introduction to the Theory of Surreal Numbers coming in the mail. Should I read those first? I just do not feel good when Conway says "the proof of this theorem is easy" and then I spend days only to get nowhere, which has happened a few times

I think that your entire thought process is correct, and that this is a mistake in ONAG.
Here is one way to fix this mistake. Instead of thinking of $1$ in its simplest form as $1=\{0\mid \}$, you need to think of it as
$$
1=\big\{\{x\in \mathbb R\mid x<1\}\mid \{x\in \mathbb R\mid x>1\}\big\}.
$$
When you do this, you find $1^R$ is no longer empty, as $1^R$ contains $2,e,\pi,$ etc, while $1^L$ contains lots of numbers, not just zero. When you follow out the $z=1$ case this line, what you get is
$$
\omega^1\cdot 1=\big\{\{\omega^1\cdot x\mid x<1\}\mid \{\omega^1\cdot x\mid x>1\}\}.
\\
=\{0.4\omega,0.9\omega,\sqrt{7/13}\omega,\dots\mid 2\omega,e\omega,\pi\omega,\dots\}
$$
Of course, this "fix" creates other problems. You initially noted that the only value of $z$ which contributes is $z=1$, because all other terms have $r_z=0$, so there is no $r_z^L$ and $r_z^R$. Well, my method means representing every real number $r$ as $r=\{\text{reals less than $r$}\mid \text{reals more than $r$}\}$, so this is no longer true. Instead, you would need say that, instead of $z\in \bf{No}$, that $z$ only ranges overs the numbers for which $r_z\neq 0$.

To your last paragraph, I would suggest reading Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron Siegel before reading ONAG. Siegel's book was written decades after ONAG, so it has the benefit of hindsight. This means the proofs are written to a more modern standard of readability, and he came up with a good way to organize the concepts to be easier to learn.
